# Android gallery viewer recycling

Tags: android, adapter, image-gallery, android-gallery

I made a gallery viewer based on [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.nl/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html) tutorial, and I'm having problems when clicking in the thumbnails.
For example if I click in the 2nd thumbnail, it goes to the 3rd, if I click in the 4th, it goes to the 5th, etc.. but if I click on the 6th, it actually goes to the 6th.
I presume it must have something to do with the position of the thumbnails and the recycling of the adapter, but I can't stumble into a solution.

This is my adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
            ta.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImagesUrls.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        // Thumbnails gallery

        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iv;
            if (arg1 == null) {
                iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            } else {
                iv = (ImageView) arg1;
            }

            // iv.setImageResource(mImagesUrls.get(arg0));
            mCache.loadBitmap(mImagesUrls.get(arg0), iv);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            // Image size of the thumbnails
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 120));
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            GalleryTitleTv.setText((arg0 + 1) + " van " + mImagesUrls.size());
            return iv;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: 
This is the caching I'm doing of the images for the thumbnails:

```
public void loadBitmap(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        Bitmap mImageHolder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.pic_2);
        final String imageKey = url;
        final Bitmap bitmap = get(imageKey);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImageHolder);
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
            task.execute(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I presume it must have something to do with the position of the
>   thumbnails and the recycling of the adapter, but I can't stumble into
>   a solution.

Since gallery does not recycle views I  think not.

```
            ImageView iv;
            if (arg1 == null) {
                iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            } else {
                iv = (ImageView) arg1;
            }
```

for the same reason this snipet is not useful. You can avoid the control and allocate the `ImageView` everytime, since arg1 will be always null. You should provide more information about you do cache your bitmap. IMHO the issue is cache or mImagesUrls related.

Comment: yes, you are right: I just read that there's a bug that makes `View` parameter always `null`.

Comment: are you using an HashMap to retrive url using the position as key and an HashMap to retrive the bitmap given the url?

Comment: I think so, is there anything bad in this approach?

Comment: there are a lot. Nevertheless your approch is correct. Maybe what's wrong is the way you store in the cache the bitmap.